# Scraping ldJSON in a node.js project

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, web-scraping

I'm working on a node.js project and need to scrape schema.org content from pages. These pages include the schema.org information as ldJSON data inside a script tag:

```
<script type=application/ld+json>
```

I tried searching online for this, but have only found pages with python solutions. I have found webpages that suggest simply using JSON.parse() to parse it. However, I need to get the contents of the script tag as indicated above before I do that. How does one get the contents of this script tag with node.js? And is JSON.parse() what is normally used in this case?

Comment: It looks like you are asking how to completely build a web scraper in NodeJS from scratch.

Comment: No I've been building out already for months. I'm looking for code samples that take an arbitrary page url, and extract out the contents of a particular type of script tag. In this case, some of the page contain schema.org data inside an ld+json script tag (as indicated above). I'm just trying to figure out how that's normally done.

Comment: Also I asked a very similar question earlier in the evening, and it was also downvoted. I'm not sure why I'm being downvoted. My previous question was also closed, because I asked about libraries used to do this, so I didn't do that this time, and asked more pointed questions. Is this question so simple that it shouldn't be asked or is it so complicated that it's a complete webscraper in a single question? I don't get it.

Comment: @BlueWater86 This question only asking how to select ldJSON script from HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this myself.

The answer is, if you're using a Puppeteer Page object, and want to select the script tag for application/ld+json, and grab the contents, you can do it this way:

```
const element  = await page.$('script[type="application/ld+json"]');
const text     = await page.evaluate(element => element.innerText, element);
const JSONparsedText = JSON.parse(text)
```

Then you can do whatever you want to the JSON object, and extract out the json data however you like. My original question was can you use a selector for the script tag and grab that innerText content. The answer is yes, the above is how.